# How to get name property from select option in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, search, input

I want to search from input field but want to get the property from the select option. Like I want mobile number to be searched from DB , but when i select mobile from select option then it should be search and if i select email then inside the input field i will post email and will select the email from select option then want to search. Here I have done some coding.

Blade file code

```
<select name="option" class="col-sm-4 form-control mg-md-l-2">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="cc" name="cc">Customer Code</option>
    <option value="cname" name="cname">Company Name</option>
    <option value="email" name="email">Email</option>
    <option value="mobile" name="mobile">Phone</option>
</select>
<div class="col-1"></div>
<input type="text" class="col-sm-6 form-control" placeholder="Type here" name="">
```

Here the controller code

```
$user_id= Auth::user()->id;
    $sale = $request->get('sales_id');
    $priority = $request->get('priority');
    $cc = $request->get('cc');
    $cname = $request->get('cname');
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $mobile = $request->get('mobile');
    $from_date = $request->input('from_date');
    $to_date = $request->input('to_date');
    if (empty($from_date)) {
        $from_date = '2019-01-01 00:00:00';
    } else {
        $from_date = $from_date . ' 00:00:00';
    }
    if (empty($to_date)) {
        $to_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    } else {
        $to_date = $to_date . ' 23:59:59';
    }
    if ($sale || $priority || $cname || $email || $mobile || $cc) {
        $customers = \DB::table('field_customers as u')
                ->where('u.cc', 'LIKE', "%{$cc}%")
                ->where('u.sales_id', 'LIKE', "%{$sale}%")
                ->where('u.priority', 'LIKE', "%{$priority}%")
                ->where('u.cname', 'LIKE', "%{$cname}%")
                ->where('u.email', 'LIKE', "%{$email}%")
                ->where('u.mobile', 'LIKE', "%{$mobile}%")
                ->whereBetween('u.followup', [$from_date, $to_date])
                ->orderBy('u.followup', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(10);
    }
    else{
        $customers = DB::table('field_customers')  
        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(20);
    }
```

Here what I want
[image]

Comment: is that `option` inside a `form` element? if we dont know how you pass that parameter to laravel, we have no idea how to help. your post hardly fulfill [mcve].

Comment: fyi, `<option>` doesn't use/send the `name` attribute

Comment: Yes option is inside a form element

Comment: Your `<select>` has `name="option"`, so `$request->get('option');` in your controller

Comment: I want that option value inside input tag.That means if i select mobile and it will be <input type="text" name="mobile"/>

Comment: Sounds overly complicated. Why not just use `name="search"` and always use that? You know what "option" to search from your `<select>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    I have found a solution of this question and that is pretty much simple to work on. You can have a look here.
    
        <select id="selector" onchange="DateCheck(this);"
class="form-control mg-md-l-2">
<option value="">All</option>
<option value="created_at">Entry Date</option>
<option value="visiting_date">Visiting Date</option>
<option value="followup">Follow-up Date</option>
</select>

<div id="created_at" style="display: none;">
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="created_at" name="created_at"
placeholder="Enter Entry Date" /><br />
</div>
<div id="visiting_date" style="display: none;">
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="visiting_date" name="visiting_date"
placeholder="Enter Visiting Date" /><br />
</div>
<div id="followup" style="display: none;">
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="followup" name="followup"
placeholder="Enter Followup Date" /><br />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function DateCheck(that) {
            if (that.value == "created_at") {
                document.getElementById("created_at").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("created_at").style.display = "none";
            }
            if (that.value == "visiting_date") {
                document.getElementById("visiting_date").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("visiting_date").style.display = "none";
            }
            if (that.value == "followup") {
                document.getElementById("followup").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("followup").style.display = "none";
            }
```